# SVN Upgrade - Possible solutions to speed it up

Tags: svn

I'm running:

```
svn upgrade
```

on an 1.2GB repo.

As you can imagine as it's progressing it's slowing down as it's locking more and more files. 
I started it at 15:00 yesterday and it's probably only 30-40% through.

I'm probably asking for a miracle, but is there anyway I can speed it up?

At this rate, it's probably not going to finish until some point into the weekend.

[Note: In the future I plan on breaking up the repo into smaller chunks, so that processes don't take so long, but that's not an option at the moment.]

Thanks!

Comment: This should take at most a little more than 20 seconds. Please provide exact svn-command with path, OS and svn version you want to upgrade from and to

Comment: Hi Peter, svn cmd: 'svn upgrade', OS is Debian Squeeze, SVN Version 1.6 to 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using a special file system that is good for that; for example **jfs**?

> svn upgrade

or

> svn update

?

Comment: Nope, that was correct: svn upgrade. We're currently using samba for our file system, it'll be too much work to move to something different.

Comment: Could you have run the upgrade on the samba server itself to at least cut out the network latency then? It's probably too late now, though, and I'd be nervous about breaking the upgrade part-way through (assuming you can take the SVN interruption today)

Comment: I guess "svnadmin upgrade" was meant (just for correctness). I agree with Rup. Also, may be the problem is that svn tried to upgrade itself via internet whereas it is a low-speed data transmission?

Comment: I'm running the upgrade directly on the server, so low-speed data isn't an issue.